# Programmatically saving a file on an Android device

Tags: android, file, save, screenshot

I'm writing some UI tests, and I need to be able to have those tests programmatically take screenshots of my application at certain points. I wasn't really sure how to even take a screenshot from inside a UI test, but I've figured that out and have slightly modified some code I found online to work for my purposes. As far as I can tell, the code to take a screenshot works just fine; however, I can't seem to save the screenshot once I take it.

The code I found seems to use the following steps to save the screenshot once it takes it. Of course, it doesn't work, like I said, but that may be because my device is a Nexus 7, and based on what I've read, storage works differently on that device than on other Android devices, although none of the resources I have seen have covered that discrepancy in much detail.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + theFileName;
File imageFile = new File(path);
```

The next bit is in a try-catch block, and it is at this point where the program throws a FileNotFound exception.

```
out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
```

("out" is a FileOutputStream)

I assume that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() is not returning the right path or something. I've also tried just .getPath instead, but that did not work either. I've checked to see what the file path of imageFile is right before defining out, and it is "/storage/emulated/0/screenname" (where screenname is theFileName in the code).

I need to save the screenshots on the device somewhere. It doesn't really matter where, so long as I can access it from my computer, but I'd like it if I could code this in such a way so that I can run the program on any device without having to rewrite the code for determining the path. If that's not possible, I'd like it to at least work on my Nexus 7.

Any suggestions as to how I could do this would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT: Manifest File**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.john.johntest.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You have a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission request in manifest file?

Comment: Doing that makes my application cease to function apparently. It begins to upload the file to my device and doesn't get any further than that.

Comment: Upload which file to your device? Where are you talking about? Better show the used code.

Comment: I have the Nexus 7 linked to my laptop, and I run the application on the Nexus from my laptop  (via Android Studio). I say "uploading the file" referring to the Nexus downloading the application from the laptop in order to run it. I'm at a different computer right now, but, when I get a chance, I'll put up the manifest file.

Comment: Your descriptions are very confusing and not correct. Your IDE installs your app on the device and then starts it. After that you can restart your app manually many times on the device. Now please restart your app as we are interested in what it does.

Comment: Whenever I update the code though, I have to reinstall the application on the device, I believe. The version with the updated manifest does not successfully install on the device, so the only version present there is an old one that fails to take the screenshot and does not have the updated manifest. As it stands, the version on the tablet right now runs just fine; it's the UI test that runs the screenshot code, not the application itself, so I don't have any problems running the app on its own.

Comment: `The version with the updated manifest does not successfully install on the device,` It is strange that adding one permission line would cause that. `it's the UI test that runs the screenshot code,`. Sorry, i have no idea where you are talking about.

Comment: The only change I've added so far was adding the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE request to the manifest, so I don't know what else could've caused it to stop working. As for the second point, I'm writing an automated UI test for the application. As the UI test runs, I need screenshots of every screen, Thus, the code that takes screenshots is executed inside of the UI test, not inside of the application itself.

Comment: Just remove that permission line and see if it installs...

Comment: If that ui test app should write to external memory then that should get the permission. I don't understand what your other app (where the screenshots are taken from) has to do with the problem. Is taking screenshots of another app possible on an unrooted device?

Comment: I have no idea why, but I let the thing sit overnight, tried to run it again this morning, and now it works, despite me having not changed a thing. The screenshot code seems to have worked now that that permission is added and the application installs properly. Thanks so much; it seems your suggestion at the beginning was the only thing that needed changing. I have no idea why it didn't work yesterday and it works now, but I'm sorry for wasting your time there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission request in your manifest file.

Comment: for anyone else who might come looking, the code is: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>